# Invalid Parameter-Binding Oracle C# in .NET Core project bulk insert using array binding

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, odp.net

I want to insert a bulk data into a oracle table using array binding.

Operational code, which is throwing an exception.

```
IList<DetailsDto> detailsListDto = new List<DetailsDto>();

query = @"INSERT INTO t115_allocdetails (c115_storeno, c115_itemno, c115_id) VALUES (:c115_storeno, :c115_itemno, :c115_id)";

long[] ids = new long[allocationDetails.Count];
long[] stores = new long[allocationDetails.Count];
string[] itemnumbers = new string[allocationDetails.Count];

for (int j = 0; j < allocationDetails.Count; j++)
{
     ids[j] = Convert.ToInt64(allocationDetails[j].Id);
     stores[j] = Convert.ToInt64(allocationDetails[j].Item.StoreNumber);
     itemnumbers[j] = Convert.ToString(allocationDetails[j].Item.ItemNumber);
}

 OracleParameter c115_storeno = new OracleParameter();
 c115_storeno.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
 c115_storeno.Value = stores;

 OracleParameter c115_itemno = new OracleParameter();
 c115_itemno.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
 c115_itemno.Value = itemnumbers;

 OracleParameter c115_id = new OracleParameter();
 c115_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
 c115_id.Value = ids;

 using (var command = dbCon.CreateCommand())
 {
     command.CommandText = query;
     command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     command.BindByName = true;
     command.ArrayBindCount = detailsListDto.Count;

     command.Parameters.Add(c115_storeno);
     command.Parameters.Add(c115_itemno);
     command.Parameters.Add(c115_id);
     await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
       }
```

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid Parameter-Binding (Parameter 'c115_storeno')

**Update Answer**

I have added following properties in each oracle parameter, and it has been resolved.

```
    c115_storeno.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    c115_storeno.ParameterName = ":c115_storeno";
    c115_itemno.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    c115_itemno.ParameterName = ":c115_itemno";
    c115_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    c115_id.ParameterName = ":c115_id";
```

Comment: You specified that `c115_storeno` is a `long`, not an array. The same for all other parameters

Comment: `VALUES` works with single values too. Unless `c115_storeno` is a VARRAY field, that `INSERT ... VALUES` won't do what you think it will. It won't insert one row per array item