# Invalid parameter binding (Parameter 'result') error when calling PL/SQL function in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, plsqldeveloper

I am getting Invalid parameter binding (Parameter 'result') error when calling PL/SQL function in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

Please help me to fix this.

This is my code:

```
var parameterConverage = new OracleParameter[] {
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam1, OracleDbType.Decimal, savePayrollReportDim.PolicyID,  ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam2, OracleDbType.Date, savePayrollReportDim.PolicyPeriodEffDate, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam3, OracleDbType.Date, savePayrollReportDim.PolicyPremiumPeriodEffDate, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam4, OracleDbType.NVarchar2, savePayrollReportDim.PremiumTypeCode, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam5, OracleDbType.NVarchar2, savePayrollReportDim.StateCode, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam6, OracleDbType.Decimal, savePayrollReportDim.LegalEntityIDBusnIns, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam7, OracleDbType.Decimal, savePayrollReportDim.RiskID, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam8, OracleDbType.NVarchar2, savePayrollReportDim.ClassCode, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam9, OracleDbType.NVarchar2, savePayrollReportDim.ClassCodeSuffix, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter(DbConstants.SavePayRollReportInParam10, OracleDbType.NVarchar2, savePayrollReportDim.RatingTypeCode, ParameterDirection.Input)
};

ExecuteRawSql(FunctionCalls.SavePayrollReport, parameterConverage);  
        
protected virtual int ExecuteRawSql(string sql, object[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        return _ieiDbContext != null ? _ieiDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, parameters) : -1;
    }
    catch (OracleException)
    {
        _ieiDbContext?.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Oracle function:

```
FUNCTION f_set_pyrl_rpt_info (
an_plcy_id                      POLICY.PLCY_ID%TYPE,
ad_plcy_prd_eff_dt              POLICY_PERIOD.PLCY_PRD_EFF_DT%TYPE,
ad_plcy_prem_prd_eff_dt         POLICY_PREMIUM_PERIOD.PLCY_PREM_PRD_EFF_DT%TYPE,
av_prem_typ_cd                  PREMIUM_TYPE.PREM_TYP_CD%TYPE,
av_stt_cd                       STATE.STT_CD%TYPE,
an_lgl_enty_id_ptcp_busn_ins    LEGAL_ENTITY.LGL_ENTY_ID%TYPE,
an_risk_id                      RISK.RISK_ID%TYPE,
av_cls_cd                       CLASS.CLS_CD%TYPE,
av_cls_cd_sufx                  CLASS.CLS_CD_SUFX%TYPE,
av_rt_typ_cd                    RATING_TYPE.RT_TYP_CD%TYPE)
 RETURN NUMBER;
```

Comment: Where did you use the `result` parameter? Have you tried adding `result` property in oracle parameter like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305094/invalid-parameter-binding-oracle-c-sharp-in-net-core-project-bulk-insert-using)?